# Getting information of same app from different devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an app which can discover devices whose Bluetooth is on. My app is available on all devices and I want to fetch info from each user's app (which I have made and they are using) and display to all of them. How can I do this?

Put simply, My app is running on multiple devices and all users are in a room. It is using Bluetooth to get data about each user and I want to display it to all the running apps.

How can I do this?

Comment: start your own bluetooth gatt service on the device, and while scanning for available devices, filter them by this service. This way you will filter only devices which have your app installed and running. Then you can go further and read/write to your service's characteristics to communicate

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks for clearing my doubts to some extent. But after filtering the devices with my apps installed, How can I connect to my own app on other devices? If could help.